# Previous fragment not loaded when pressing Back button using BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have an `activity_main.xml` with an `BottomNavigationView` and a `NavHostFragment`.

There are 2 tabs, `HomeFragment` with a video and `FavoritesFragment`. Within `FavoritesFragment` there is a list of favorite video's (thumbnails) and when I click on an item it loads the `HomeFragment` view with that specific video.

within `mobile_navigation.xml` I have defined the `HomeFragment` twice. 1 is the Home Tab and 1 is the "Favorite" when clicked on the thumbnail in `FavoritesFragment`.

[image]

When I click the back button I expect to be back in the `FavoriteFragment`. But the App shuts down.

When the thumbnail is clicked, this code is executed:

```
            val action = FavoritesFragmentDirections
                .actionNavigationFavoritesToNavigationFavorite(imageUri)
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@FavoritesFragment)
                .navigate(action)
```

I also tried this:

```
protected fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment, uniqueName: String) {
    activity?.supportFragmentManager
        ?.beginTransaction()
        ?.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        ?.addToBackStack(uniqueName)
        ?.commitAllowingStateLoss()
}
```

But same result.

With this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()

    if (!navController.popBackStack()) {
        // Call finish() on your Activity
        finish()
    }
}
```

The back button goes back to the `HomeFragment`, instead of `FavoritesFragment`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="eu.theappfactory.dailyrecipes.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <argument
            android:name="imageuri"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
        android:name="eu.theappfactory.dailyrecipes.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorites" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_favorites_to_navigation_favorite"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_favorite" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_favorite"
        android:name="eu.theappfactory.dailyrecipes.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <argument
            android:name="imageuri"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Hey, could you also add the code for your navigation graph?

Comment: check this https://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/#:~:text=But%20fragments%20do%20not%20get,navigate%20back%20through%20the%20fragments.

Comment: added the code for the navigation graph..

Comment: "But the App shuts down." - so what is the stack trace when it shuts down?

Comment: nothing special. Nothing red. Some generic info messages.

Comment: why you handle `onBackPressed()` when use navigation component ?!

Comment: I don't handle onBackPressed it was just given as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't know how kotlin works in android but here's how you should set it up,
onBack press only goes to the previous activity and if there isn't one it shuts down,
Since you have 1 activity and multiple fragments what you should do is override the onBackpress method and call the previous fragment and if none exist you should close the app, not after overriding onBackPress you will have to exit the app manually, I'm gonna share my java code, see if you can scavenge from it

```
private void onBackAction() {
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Note the popBackStack only reopens a fragment if there is one the stack.

Answer (score -1):

Try override onBackPressed method in the host activity and place the code:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(!navController.popBackStack())
        finish()
}
```